# Create a redirector method to another object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `Roo` and class `Fee`.

Class `Fee` has an instance of `Roo` stored in a property called `RooInstance`.

To redirect all `Fee` method calls to `RooInstance`, I could simply do:

`public void TheMethod() => RooInstance.TheMethod();`

The problem is - `RooInstance` has at least 60 methods and since I can list them all (with details) at runtime, I was wondering if I could somehow create a method at runtime for each of them and attach it to the type.

I think it's possible, since ExpandoObject works in such a way - but I'm unable to inherit from it **plus the class I'm using is static and is meant to stay that way**.

It's .NET Core

Comment: Is this full .net or .net core? Also, do you need to have `Fee` methods known at compile time? Because this sounds like a candidate for Reflection.Emit.

Comment: Very unclear what you want to achieve... What would be a value of a static class that only gets methods at run time? (I personally think what you are trying to do is flat out bad idea... but people like singletons and just static methods... partially to get an excuse to not have tests as it is hard to test code that uses static methods :) )

Comment: Side note: you may have good reasons to call your approach "redirector" but it sounds you simply building "proxy"...

Comment: @zaitsman It's core

Comment: But do you need to know methods at compile time?

Comment: @zaitsman Not really. I was just hoping to automate the process of creating the proxy.